# PHP: Split string into same amount of chars and if it's too big find last \n and continue from there?

Tags: php, string, split, char

I have a string which is quite long. The length of the string is variable and not static. That's why I need to write a dynamic function for my problem. However, I have to split my string into equal big sizes. The max size per string is 4096 chars.

This is actually quite easy to do this:

```
$myArray = str_split($myMessage, 4096);
```

The problem I am now facing is that I want split the string after each 4096s char but also have it readable. So, what I actually want is a function which splits the string after 4096 chars but then goes back to the last line break (`\n`) and then continues from there again.

So, at the end I have a quite readable string which is always splited by the 4096s (if the 4096s char  is a `\n`) or the last `\n`.

However, I already googled but didn't found a solution.. Could you guys help me and give me a hint how to solve this cause I don't really have a glue how to solve this..

So, here is a example of what I want at the end with a max char length of 5:

```
$myString = "Hey there.\nThis is a test.\nAnd this is\nhow it works."

[0] = "Hey there.\nThis is a test.\n"; //29 chars
[1] = "And this is\nhow it works.";
```

Kind regards and thank you!

Comment: I'm thinking you would be better off using `strpos` looking for the first instance of `/n` then check if it is under your maximum length and then splitting it from that using `substr`, and looping that procedure till the string is empty if I am understanding your question correctly.

Comment: @jan why would a max char length of 5 produce that output? I find this question's requirements to be unclear.  I am confident that I can devise a solution after the [mcve] is made clear.

Answer (score 0):

so I got this to do what you wanted:

```
$myString = "Hey there.<br />This is a test.<br />And this is<br />how it works.";
$array1 = str_split($myString, 30);
$array2 = explode('<br />', $array1[0]);
for($i=0; $i<count($array2); $i++){
    echo $array2[$i].'<br />';
}
```

The issue I had was with the string in the first place trying to find `\n` I changed this to a `<br />` and it was much easier to do. Not sure if you will be able to change your string like this in the first place.

Comment: I don't think that you are addressing the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "Hey there.\nThis is a test.\nAnd this is\nhow it works.";
//Your long string with \n

$len = 20;
//The longest length of each chunk

$needle = "\n";
//The character you want to split the strings by

while(strlen($string)>$len){
    //as long as the string is longer than 1 chunk

    $len_chunk = substr($string, 0, $len);
    //cut away the first chunk

    $string = substr($string, $len);
    //keep the rest together

    if(!strrpos($len_chunk, $needle)){
        //in case the chunk doesn't contain a single \n character (! used instead of === FALSE by design)
        $chunks[] = $len_chunk;
        continue;
    }

    $chunks[] = substr($len_chunk, 0, strrpos($len_chunk, $needle));
    //trim away the stuff after the *last* \n

    $string = substr($len_chunk, strrpos($len_chunk, $needle)) . $string;
    //Attach the rest back to the original string
}

$chunks[] = $string;
//Add whatever is remaining in the string as the last chunk!

var_dump($chunks);
```

The output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "Hey there."
  [1]=>
  string(16) "
This is a test."
  [2]=>
  string(12) "
And this is"
  [3]=>
  string(14) "
how it works."
}
```

The way the code is at the moment, the \n comes *first* in each subsequent string after the first. This can easily be changed to be the *last* character of reach string or removed altogether.

Comment: I do get `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 134217736 bytes)`. And also, where is my array? Is it the `$chunks` variable?

Comment: Ya. I've commented the code, hopefully that will be clearer.

Comment: But why do I get `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 134217736 bytes)` if I change the length to 5 e.g. This message only comes up if the length is quite low!

Comment: I added a failsafe, what is happening is that you have chunks that don't contain a single \n

Comment: So much of computation power and still not the correct solution.

Comment: @roundAbout, please elaborate. Or add your own answer. There are many ways to skin this cat.

Comment: Hey @dearsina, can you please try this with a chunk length of 4000 and a text which gets chunked 3 or more times? Cause I am facing the problem that the last chunk doesn't get add to the chunk array. And its always the last few words which are over after chunking the text..